# How do i add multiple choice field during registration ?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I have two queries here
1)
How do i add multiple choice field during registration?

Along with username / email I want one more custom field like input your interest 
this can be accompanied by multiple choice inputs (checkboxes)

e.g. 
What computer languages you know 
--- C
--- C++
--- PHP
--- Python
user should be allowed to select one or more inputs .

It will be even better if i can populate the Questions based on user type. For example if user type is student then he should be asked different set of multiple choice questions.

Comment: Show what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

The first one should be fairly easy- add a new field to user, make it a select type, check the box to make it required, set it to allow multiple selections, add your list of computer languages to the options list.

For the second, that's going to be more complicated and you probably need to write a custom module for that.